# How to keep threads paused in C

Tags: c, multithreading, ubuntu, matrix, pthreads

I have several pairs of matrices contained in a single text file, what I need is to load the first pair, use threads to perform multiplication, output the result, load the next pair and do the same until I'm out of pairs. The problem is I'm creating threads for every pair, and I need to create threads just once in order to save time compared to the sequential version of the code, and use them every time a new pair of matrices is loaded. I have tried with signal conditions and so, but nothing so far.

Edit: Allocating, loading and printing are all in the main function. The threads are only there to perform a fine-grained multiplication on every pair

The finGrain.c file is this:
[fileGrain.c](https://codeshare.io/2K6Re8)

Comment: Your question is little confusing. Do you want one thread loading pairs from files and one thread multiplying pairs?

Comment: Allocating, loading and printing are all in the main function. The threads are only there to perform a fine-grained multiplication on every pair.

Comment: Could you please show us that what have you done already?

Comment: I have shared a link up there

Comment: You may use thread pool for this purpose. There are several open source implementations of threadpool for pthread library like https://github.com/Maratyszcza/pthreadpool

Comment: Please don't 'share links'.  Show the code in the question.  Please read about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).